# WMIC Node Information

Tags: command-line, remote, wmic

Is there a way that you can get WMIC to prompt you for a node name each time?
I will be running a similar command for different machines on different occasions.

I.e. to get a remote computer model.

I would like to run the WMIC as a BAT file which then prompts for a node name?

```
wmic /node:"PROMPT computersystem list brief /format:list
```

Thanks,
Shane

Comment: From `Set /?`: "The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input entered by the user.  Displays the specified promptString before reading the line of input."

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are asking.

```
set /p N= Type Node Name
wmic /node:"%N% computersystem list brief /format:list
```